# How do I create different object using the same function?

Tags: javascript, pixi.js

I have a function that creates a button and when I call this function to create different buttons, all the buttons end up merged somehow. I started JS 2 days ago, and learnt AS3 for some months for fun. JS looks so weird to me, I barely understand the logic behind the language, yet people told me AS3 and JS are very similar!

I tried classes, calling new,... no luck so far :/ I'm really running out of ideas, and whatever I read, it all doesn't click.

```
var definitions = new Definitions();
var btnCounter = 0;

var btnHighlight = private function (row, column, imageLink, variable, callF) {

    btnCounter++;

    name = "btnHl " + btnCounter;
    active = variable;
    defintions = definitions;
    callFunction = callF;

    button = new PIXI.Sprite(PIXI.Texture.from(imageLink));
    button.anchor.set(0.5);
    button.width = definitions.buttonIconSize;
    button.height = definitions.buttonIconSize;

    highlight = new PIXI.Sprite(PIXI.Texture.from('images/highlightGfx.png'));
    highlight.anchor.set(0.5);
    highlight.width = definitions.buttonHighlightSize;
    highlight.height = definitions.buttonHighlightSize;

    buttonContainer = new PIXI.Container();
    buttonContainer.buttonMode = true;
    buttonContainer.interactive = true;
    buttonContainer.buttonMode = true;
    buttonContainer.y = definitions.editorItemSize / 2 + definitions.editorItemSize * row;
    buttonContainer.x = definitions.editorItemSize / 2 + definitions.editorItemSize * column;
    buttonContainer.addChild(button);

    buttonContainer.on('pointerdown', onButtonDown = function () {
        if (active) {
            buttonContainer.removeChild(highlight);
            active = false;
        } else {
            active = true;
            buttonContainer.addChild(highlight);
        }
        if (callFunction != null) {
            callFunction();
        }
        console.log(name);
    });

    if (active == true) {
        buttonContainer.addChild(highlight);
    }

    return buttonContainer;
}

var testThis = function () {
    console.log("clicked");
    return this;
}

var btnDevicePhone = new btnHighlight(0, 0, 'images/transformGfx.png', true, testThis);
var btnDeviceTablette = new btnHighlight(0, 1, 'images/transformGfx.png', true, testThis);
var btnDeviceDesktop = new btnHighlight(1, 0, 'images/transformGfx.png', true, testThis);
var btnDeviceOrientation = new btnHighlight(1, 1, 'images/transformGfx.png', true, testThis);
var btnDrawSquare = new btnHighlight(2, 0, 'images/transformGfx.png', true, testThis);
var btnDrawCircle = new btnHighlight(2, 1, 'images/transformGfx.png', true, testThis);
var btnDropSquare = new btnHighlight(3, 0, 'images/transformGfx.png', true, testThis);
var btnDropCircle = new btnHighlight(3, 1, 'images/transformGfx.png', true, testThis);

app.stage.addChild(
    btnDevicePhone,
    btnDeviceTablette,
    btnDeviceDesktop,
    btnDeviceOrientation,
    btnDrawSquare,
    btnDrawCircle,
    btnDropSquare,
    btnDropCircle, );
```

Console.log always prints the same name for all the buttons. Aren't all the "new" calls supposed to create a new object? What's going on here?

Comment: A source for this question: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new

Comment: I completely fail to see how it's explaining my problem, I'm very new to this, if anything, what I've just read tells me that I did the right thing :/ which definitly isn't right haha !

Comment: Look at the answer, I hope that helps you succeed - and there’s a typo in your code: **defintions** instead of **definitions**

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more detailed example for an answer:

```js
// this is a constructor function
// it "stands by itself", so no 'new' keyword, no var before it
// pay attention to the "this" before the variables you want as public properties
// this is the "skeleton" for your buttons (like a "scaffold")
function btnHighlight(counter, nameBase) {
  this.counter = counter;
  this.nameBase = nameBase;
  this.name = function() {
    return this.nameBase + "_" + this.counter
  };
}

// mockup constructor function (stage) and object (app)
function stage() {
  this.addChild = function(item) {
    this.btns.push(item);
  }
  this.btns = [];
}

var app = {};

// this is just a mockup object
app.stage = new stage();

// creating 10 new buttons
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  // here the "new" keyword is used, as we create
  // a "new" button with every iteration
  var newBtn = new btnHighlight(i, "btnHl");
  // we add the new button to the stage
  // this "imitates" the app.stage.addChild()
  app.stage.addChild(newBtn);
}

// display the stage with the 10 buttons in the console
console.log("all the 10 buttons: ");
console.log(app.stage);

// or display just one button from the array - for example the fourth
// remember stage[0] is the first button!
console.log("the fourth button: ");
console.log(app.stage.btns[3]);

// or display just one button's name - for example the sixth
// see that "name" is a function, so it's called with parantheses after it
// remember stage[0] is the first button!
console.log("the sixth button's name: ");
console.log("sixth button's name: " + app.stage.btns[5].name());

// let's modify the second buttons nameBase property, and see that only that buttons name has changed:
app.stage.btns[1].nameBase = 'olive';
console.log("changed the second button's nameBase, so name is also changed: ");
app.stage.btns.forEach(item => console.log(item.name()))
```

So your code look more like this:

```
var definitions = new Definitions();
var btnCounter = 0;

// the constructor function is created here
function btnHighlight(row, column, imageLink, variable, callF, btnCounter) {

  // properties are added, using "this"
  this.name = "btnHl " + btnCounter;
  this.active = variable;
  this.defintions = definitions;
  this.callFunction = callF;

  this.button = new PIXI.Sprite(PIXI.Texture.from(imageLink));
  button.anchor.set(0.5);
  button.width = definitions.buttonIconSize;
  button.height = definitions.buttonIconSize;

  this.highlight = new PIXI.Sprite(PIXI.Texture.from('images/highlightGfx.png'));
  highlight.anchor.set(0.5);
  highlight.width = definitions.buttonHighlightSize;
  highlight.height = definitions.buttonHighlightSize;

  this.buttonContainer = new PIXI.Container();
  buttonContainer.buttonMode = true;
  buttonContainer.interactive = true;
  buttonContainer.buttonMode = true;
  buttonContainer.y = definitions.editorItemSize / 2 + definitions.editorItemSize * row;
  buttonContainer.x = definitions.editorItemSize / 2 + definitions.editorItemSize * column;
  buttonContainer.addChild(button);

  buttonContainer.on('pointerdown', onButtonDown = function() {
    if (active) {
      buttonContainer.removeChild(highlight);
      active = false;
    } else {
      active = true;
      buttonContainer.addChild(highlight);
    }
    if (callFunction != null) {
      callFunction();
    }
    console.log(name);
  });

  if (active == true) {
    buttonContainer.addChild(highlight);
  }

  return buttonContainer;
}

var testThis = function() {
  console.log("clicked");
  return this;
}

// creating the buttons, and then incrementing the counter
var btnDevicePhone = new btnHighlight(0, 0, 'images/transformGfx.png', true, testThis, btnCounter);
btnCounter++;
var btnDeviceTablette = new btnHighlight(0, 1, 'images/transformGfx.png', true, testThis, btnCounter);
btnCounter++;
var btnDeviceDesktop = new btnHighlight(1, 0, 'images/transformGfx.png', true, testThis, btnCounter);
btnCounter++;
var btnDeviceOrientation = new btnHighlight(1, 1, 'images/transformGfx.png', true, testThis, btnCounter);
btnCounter++;
var btnDrawSquare = new btnHighlight(2, 0, 'images/transformGfx.png', true, testThis, btnCounter);
btnCounter++;
var btnDrawCircle = new btnHighlight(2, 1, 'images/transformGfx.png', true, testThis, btnCounter);
btnCounter++;
var btnDropSquare = new btnHighlight(3, 0, 'images/transformGfx.png', true, testThis, btnCounter);
btnCounter++;
var btnDropCircle = new btnHighlight(3, 1, 'images/transformGfx.png', true, testThis, btnCounter);

// adding the buttons to the stage
app.stage.addChild(
  btnDevicePhone,
  btnDeviceTablette,
  btnDeviceDesktop,
  btnDeviceOrientation,
  btnDrawSquare,
  btnDrawCircle,
  btnDropSquare,
  btnDropCircle, );
```

I'm not sure, if your modified code here is error free (as I cannot test it), but it should be working.

**EDIT**

Final answer can be found on **codepen.io**

[https://codepen.io/mukagergely/pen/YbWBWR?editors=1111](http://codepen.io/mukagergely/pen/YbWBWR?editors=1111)

Comment: Nagyon, nagyon köszönöm ! I tried everything you did, but in my code it's not working for me :/. First, functions do not allow me to add a property with "this", then call that property inside the same function without the "this" again,  then I can feel that you're holding the right answer, but weirdly I believe it's not working with PIXI. When all the buttons are on the stage, whichever I click, makes only the last one react, but all 8 buttons are there, at the right place! Is it possible that PIXI is broken? That same instances aren't rightfully handled by PIXI?

Comment: I need to install PIXI first, I can only say more after that. Wouldn’t you have your project on Github by any chance, so I can just clone it? I need a couple of hours as I’m at the movies with family... :)

Comment: Hey there, well I only started and have no account on Github. But I can copy paste it in here, it's 1 file only, as I'm learning.

Comment: Hey Muka! I replaced the "this" parts in your code by "let", and everything works !!! Thanks a lot for your help !! Just tryed "var", and it works too !!

Comment: Here's a codepen: https://codepen.io/mukagergely/pen/YbWBWR?editors=1111. I'm happy that it works for you, but a constructor should be used with **this** - that references the object. **let** is a scoped variable (mutable), and may cause problems later on. Just scan through the pen, to see what's different (open the console, and you'll see that everything works fine with **this**) :)

Comment: wow, thanks for your time!! I'll read this like a bible :D, köszi köszi !! Jo az ido magyarorszagon? :D

Comment: I'm happy that I could help! :) Az idő ma egészen csodálatos volt! :) Te merre vagy? Egyébként, ha van még kérdés, akkor a profilomon lévő email címen beszélhetünk közvetlenül (vagy LinkedIn - muka.gergely). Bár PIXI-ben nem vagyok igazán jártas, de Phaser.io-val már dolgoztam (PIXI-t is használ) :D Egy upvote-ot megér a válasz? ;)

Comment: hey, nem tudom hogy to upvote lol. Belgium ba vagyok és bocs, nem jol beszelek magyarul, de probalom :D, mar regen nem voltan magyarorszagon, hijanzik :/ LinkedInom : Nicolas Johan M. Es, meg egyszer, nagyon koszonom a segitseget !!